# LINQ - extract properties values into arrays

Tags: linq

I have an List of objects and I need to get the values of each property into arrays without iterating the list more than once.
Here is the current code.
I can't seem to figure out if I can do this using Linq and only iterate the list once.

```
var numberOfItems = invoiceItemNotes.Count;
var postingRcNum = new decimal [numberOfItems];
var postingLocNum = new decimal[numberOfItems];
var invoiceNum = new decimal[numberOfItems];
var orderItemLineNum = new decimal[numberOfItems];
var seqNum = new decimal[numberOfItems];
var text = new string[numberOfItems];
int index = 0;
foreach (var invoiceItemNote in invoiceItemNotes)
{
    postingRcNum[index] = invoiceItemNote.POSTING_RC_NUM;
    postingLocNum[index] = invoiceItemNote.POSTING_LOC_NUM;
    invoiceNum[index] = invoiceItemNote.INVOICE_NUM;
    orderItemLineNum[index] = invoiceItemNote.ORDER_ITEM_LINE_NUM;
    seqNum[index] = invoiceItemNote.SEQ_NUM;
    text[index] = invoiceItemNote.TEXT;
    index++;
}
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = InvoiceInsertCommands.InsertItemNote;
    cmd.BindByName = true;
    cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
    cmd.ArrayBindCount = numberOfItems;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(InvoiceItemNoteParameters.PostingRcNum, OracleDbType.Decimal, postingRcNum, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(InvoiceItemNoteParameters.PostingLocNum, OracleDbType.Decimal, postingLocNum, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(InvoiceItemNoteParameters.InvoiceNum, OracleDbType.Decimal, invoiceNum, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(InvoiceItemNoteParameters.OrderItemLineNum, OracleDbType.Decimal, orderItemLineNum, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(InvoiceItemNoteParameters.SeqNum, OracleDbType.Decimal, seqNum, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(InvoiceItemNoteParameters.Text, OracleDbType.Varchar2, text, ParameterDirection.Input);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to have all these arrays?

Comment: If your list is a `List<T>` then `Count` is a property.  I only see you iterating through the list once, am I missing something?

Comment: The reason for the arrays is that I need pass them to a oracle in one call instead of making one call for each row.

Comment: Michael - my existing code does have only one iterations as you mention. I was hoping I could get the arrays populated using LINQ.  I want to avoid having to declare the arrays.  I have another piece of code similar to the above that I has 50+ properties and I wanted to avoid having to declare an array for each property.  Also you are correct my List is a generic list.  My end goal if possible is replace the array declaration code and for loop with a single linq statement that would return back the arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Simple.

```
object[] invoiceItemNotes = new object[10];
int index = 0;
var invoiceItemNote = invoiceItemNotes[index];
```

Comment: I feel like this is a patch file without the context lines. Can you make it clearer just exactly what changes you're suggesting?

Comment: You are enumerating through a for loop in your code which is iterating through the array invoiceItemNotes.  You don't need a for loop (nor LINQ).  Simply set invoiceItemNote to the index value you want.  If you are using Linq then select FirstOrDefault to select the first member of the Linq or use Skip() and Take(1) methods to get a single item out of an array.

Comment: The thing is I don't want once particular item in the the array.  I want to get an array for each of the six properties of InvoiceItemNote.  I know I can do it this way if I wanted just one property var posting_rcNums = invoiceItemNotes.Select(x => x.postingRcNum).ToArray().  I could write the above line 6 times once for each property, but then I would be iterating the list 6 times.  That is what I want to avoid if possible.

Comment: Linq returns a singleton object. So the easiest way of getting your results is to create an interface or class.  I prefer a class object with six items in the class each being an array.  You linq will have six select methods to iterate and fill each of the 6 arrays.  So you are really still iterating through the array 6 times without using a for loop.  A rose is a rose is a rose no matter what you call it.